# LayoutParams Gravity Right not enforcing

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-view

I'm extending a LinearLayout to make a compound widget. The widget is set to layout_width="MATCH_PARENT".

```
mLabelTextView = new TextView(context);
mLabelTextView.setText("Testing");
LayoutParams labelParams = new
LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.0f);
labelParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;
addView(mLabelTextView, labelParams);

mContentView = new Checkbox(content);
contentParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f);
contentParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.Right;

addView(mContentView, contentParams);
```

My problem is that the Gravity.Right property is taking effect on mContentView, but Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL is. I know that mContentView is getting stretched to fill the remaining space. I've already tried just getting gravity=right by itself and that didn't work.

I have a similar code path in which I inflate a view that already has right gravity set in XML and that is working. So I must be missing something somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your parent `LinearLayout` has horizontal orientation (which you don't specify, but I'm guessing), then it will ignore all horizontal layout gravity bits. Likewise, if it has vertical orientation, then it would have ignored the `CENTER_VERTICAL` setting.

One trick is to wrap `mContentView` in a vertically oriented `LinearLayout`, give that wrapper a layout weight of 1 (so it fills the remaining space) and then the wrapper will honor the `RIGHT` gravity.

A better alternative might be to extend `RelativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout`. That gives you 2-D control over gravity (unlike `LinearLayout`).

Comment: Thanks Ted. That makes perfect sense. I'll go with the RelativeLayout because I rather not introduce another level into my tree. And yes, it is horizontal orientation.